# A keyboard with a mind of it own (Linux-related?; Chromebook)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, keyboard, code

I activated Linux (beta) on my Chromebook (Google Chrome OS 85), and entered some text before installing [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and entering a very small amount of text.

A day later, my keyboard is acting sporadically. Backspace produces "gh'" and space bar produces "zvx,m?>."

Every key I've tried has produced similarly irregular results. Immediately following my "coding" (or attempts to code) yesterday, I was able to use my keyboard without issue. Sometimes, when I type, a small box displaying simply "US" appears under the search bar I'm attempting to use. The language and input in "Settings" seem normal.

I'm not certain the coding attempts caused the keyboard irregularity; I'm just giving the information I have available with hopes of solving any issues.

Of note: the Chrome browser was acting a little bit sporadically last night, switching between tabs rapidly. Also, I came across this example (https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110416133956AAfcvgP&guccounter=2&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi55YWhvby5jb20v&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAGFo8cE8PvQVJNB1ENxHoMnEpZNaa_WpgaJ2Wr6sa9WsixMczSKy0tT11Q9ELuqfH6mJbl22R4hmLIY7BcDlgtfeTQca9HcYUt7S4vtf2pNtd0DT3LsIv6RvoCIX9DFGYj4SFSeIdJY5OaEe8mM65327ZLZum-DpryDmwDkX-oye) of someone else's space bar producing zvx,m?> from ~ten years ago. Any clue?

A hard reset seems to have worked well. I remain curious.

Comment: Try plugging in another keyboard and try using he on-screen keyboard. https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/6076237?hl=en That would distinguish between hardware and software issues.

Comment: Thank you! The on-screen keyboard (new to me) worked, which means - uh,oh, it's likely hardware? Thanks

Comment: It *could* be hardware, or drivers. Borrow or buy another keyboard (some are US$5 or less) to check again. Also do a full reboot, and then update, to check or drivers.

Comment: A hard reset seems to have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question.

1. Run the keyboard troubleshooter (if there is).
2. Update/Reinstall the keyboard driver.
3. Drain your laptop battery.
4. Try your keyboard on a different PC.
5. Use external keyboard instead of your laptop keyboard.
6. Make sure that Sticky Keys aren't enabled.
7. Install the latest updates.

If this is something within you having a school Chromebook, please contact your IT.